# Select records at random using extbase's QueryBuilder

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x

I’m working on a bespoke extension in TYPO3 version 8.

In my extension I want to display three items in the front end in a random order out of a result set of at least ten or so.

As an example
(Select only three people at random and pass them to a view )

My first though was to look at the QueryBuilder and create a custom query. Looking at other similar posts it would seem that extbase’s query builder doesn’t carry a RAND function (with good reason).

Would it be better to look at using Fluid and the iterator viewhelper to help me show items in a random order? Or can it be achieved using the QueryBuilder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Extbase Repository Query does not have any Random functions. At least the new Doctrine Querybuilder since TYPO3 8 LTS can be used to get random results: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/latest/ApiOverview/Database/QueryBuilder/Index.html

On this QueryBuilder you can use `addSelectLiteral` to insert a RAND() function to the DB query. But you have to make sure that **your Database Software supports this function** since the TYPO3 DB can be connected to any other DB software which maybe doesnt support RAND().

Usage example:

```
$rows = $queryBuilder
        ->select('*')
        ->from('tx_yourext_domain_model_example')
        ->addSelectLiteral('RAND() AS randomnumber')
        ->orderBy('randomnumber')
        ->setMaxResults(3)
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAll();
```

To create some Extbase Model Records from the result you can use the DataMapper.

```
$dataMapper = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Mapper\DataMapper::class);
$result = $dataMapper->map(\You\Yourext\Model\Example::class, $rows);
```

Comment: Same way i am getting Error in 10.4.8
``(1/1) ArgumentCountError
Too few arguments to function TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Mapper\DataMapper::__construct(), 0 passed in /html/typo3/typo3_src-10.4.8/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php on line 3423 and at least 7 expected``

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a build in way in TYPO3, Fluid or QueryBuilder to do this. The way I would solve it depends on how many records there are in total.

If it's just a few dozen I'd probably select them all and use the PHP `shuffle` function to sort them randomly and then show the first 3.

If there can be hundreds or more records, I'd probably do a count and get 3 random numbers between 0 and the result of the count. You can then do 3 different queries using `setFirstResult` (the random number) and `setMaxResults` (1) functions.

Answer (score 1):

I do not use vhs in TYPO3v9. I use seconds and simple math to get 1 random element. For example, I get the random value of the iterator from the {news} array through:

```
<f:variable name="sec4random" value="{f:format.date(date:'0 seconds', format:'s')}"/>
<f:variable name="count4random" value="{f:count(subject: news)}"/>
Random index for iterator: {sec4random % count4random}
```

To access the newsItem with the found index, you could add the following:

```
 <f:variable name="newsindex" value="{sec4random % count4random}"/>
 <f:variable name="newsItem" value="{news.{newsindex}}"/>
```

Now {newsItem} contains the random single news out of the {news} array.